# Runtime Error 1004 “Application-defined or Object-defined error” while trying to reinitialise

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to run a simple VBA excel script. At one point, I need to set the variable back to zero. If I try to do this, I am getting the error "VBA Runtime Error 1004 “Application-defined or Object-defined error” while trying to reinitialise the variable ans. Am I doing something wrong?

```
Sub macro1()
Dim row As Integer
Dim trial As Integer
Dim ans As Integer
Dim amp As Double

row = 48
trial = 25
ans = 0
amp = 0

Do While Cells(row, 2) <> ""
  If Cells(row, 2).Value = trial Then
       If Cells(row, 21).Value > amp Then
           ans = row
           amp = Cells(row, 21).Value
           row = row + 1
           Debug.Print (amp)
       Else
           row = row + 1
       End If
   Else
       Cells(ans, 39).Value = amp
       row = row + 1
       trial = trial + 1
       ans = 0  // Problem in this line
       End If


   Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem actually occurs on this line:

```
Cells(ans, 39) = amp
```

The reason is because the value of `ans` is 0, and cells are not "zero indexed"; the first row is 1, not 0.

Try initializing everything with 1, instead of 0:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim trial As Integer
    Dim ans As Integer
    Dim amp As Double

    row = 48
    trial = 25
    ans = 1
    amp = 1

    Do While Cells(row, 2) <> ""
      If Cells(row, 2).Value = trial Then
           If Cells(row, 21).Value > amp Then
               ans = row
               amp = Cells(row, 21).Value
               row = row + 1
               Debug.Print (amp)
           Else
               row = row + 1
           End If
       Else
           Cells(ans, 39) = amp
           row = row + 1
           trial = trial + 1
           ans = 1
           End If
    Loop
End Sub
```